# I finished installing devstack on CentOS 7 and gave this error in the log: ... / wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, openstack

I installed devstack according to the documentation and when finished I was missing a django module as I understand it. I have already disabled SElinux, Firewalld and NetworkManager, I would like help to solve this problem, I have researched a lot and I have not found the solution.

Here is the full log:

> `2020-01-20 10:55:42.036719 mod_wsgi (pid=25003): Target WSGI script '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
>   2020-01-20 10:55:42.036828 mod_wsgi (pid=25003): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py'.
>   2020-01-20 10:55:42.036953 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2020-01-20 10:55:42.037045   File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
>   2020-01-20 10:55:42.037299     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   2020-01-20 10:55:42.037367 ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi`

Comment: Provide your wsgi script and also environment pip freeze

Comment: Please place it in as question edit :)